# How to make border around elements?

Tags: css, border

i want to make border around my element [in my page](http://touchdowner.cz/), but have a hard time to get is like i want. I want to make border the same like [here](http://piratarmy.sk/), so want to  have this elements in border. i think that is this CSS class:

```
.image-icon img {
max-width: 70%!important;
margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what to change?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the example of what you need to do have no borders around the elements any way you can create a border around elements by three ways

1.[border:1px solid #cc;] borderSize BorderStyle BorderColor,

2.[outline:1px solid #ccc;} OutlineBorderSize OutlineBorderStyle OutlineBorderColor

3.[box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #ccc;] or for inside border [box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #ccc;] first tow numbers is for shadow position and the third for the blur of the shadow and the fourth is for shadow size and you can ignore it if its normal shadow not using it as border :)